# Is Captain America a Nationalist?

Tags: marvel, captain-america

Considering that he not only fought for the country in WW2, but is also pro-military and pro-authoritarian as apparent from several *Captain America* and *Avengers* films, is it too far fetched to think that he could be considered a right wing nationalist in today's age?

Comment: If he was pro-authoritarian...wouldn't he have *happily* signed the Sokovia Accords?

Comment: Being authoritarian doesn't necessarily mean that you have to support the wrong thing, the question of "who's authority" matters.

Answer (score 3):

This may vary depending on which Captain America you choose, but it seems unlikely for Steve Rogers, as per [this story](https://newrepublic.com/article/117241/captain-americas-moral-philosophy):

> In a story from the early 1980s, Captain America uses his amazing powers to destroy a renegade American intelligence agency that is plotting an attack on the Soviet Union in order to make the United States the last remaining superpower. Confronting the plotters, the comic-book hero makes one of many declarations of faith that resound throughout his more than 70-year-long career as a fighter against evil: “I represent the American dream! A dream that has precious little to do with borders, boundaries, and the kind of blind hatred your ilk espouses!”

Steve Rogers was originally designed by some very liberal creators, and the idea was that he espoused the central values and morality of America, no matter what the politics of the leaders, to the point that he resigned as Captain America in *Captain America #332* in our 1987 after learning of great corruption in the government.

However, some incarnations of Captain America, such as [William Burnside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America_(William_Burnside)), probably would follow a much more isolationist policy.

> The FBI set up Burnside, as "Steve Rogers", a teacher at the private preparatory Lee High School in Connecticut. While there, Burnside encounters an intense advocate in James "Jack" Monroe who shares his obsessive fascination with the original Captain America. When the communist Red Skull attacks the United Nations in an elaborate scheme, Burnside injects himself and Monroe with a sample of the unproven Super-Soldier serum and confronts the Red Skull as the new Cap and Bucky. However, without the vita-ray exposure the original Rogers received to activate and stabilize the serum, Burnside and Monroe undergo a dangerously flawed application. Although initially accepted in the roles of Captain America and Bucky, the formula they ingested eventually gives them psychotic symptoms. The two become unreliable and paranoid, attacking innocents simply for their race or for holding opinions that differ from their own. They are arrested and put into suspended animation by government agents.